# Why doesn't my flutter_native_splash work?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I launch the app, the background color works, but the image doesn't show. I have my assets folder in my root directory, and the directory address is matched correctly, but the error persists.

I followed [these steps](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) and have this as my pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#000000"
  image: assets/icon_500.png
```

My image size is 500x500 and is a png. (I've tried other sizes as well but ex. 120x120, 200x200 to no avail)

here is my code that runs

```
void main() {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const Main());
  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
}
```

I ran these terminal commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:remove

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: todo_time_app
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: "none"

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.6 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
  flutter_native_timezone: ^2.0.0
  localstorage: ^4.0.0+1
  rxdart: ^0.27.7

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.17

flutter_native_splash:
 color: "#000000"
 image: assets/icon.png
 android: true
 ios: true
 web: false
 android_gravity: fill
 ios_content_mode: scaleAspectFill
 fullscreen: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

*Edit: I moved the flutter native splash as a dev dependency to see if anything would change. It was initially a regular dependency.

*Edit 2: I've checked my drawables located at "android\app\src\main\res", and the images are generated properly but they are not showing up when I run the app.

****Solution***: I added "android_12:" under "flutter_native_splash:" with seperate image and color and it worked.

[picture of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L2Un.png)

Comment: Have you added the image to assets in pubspec.ymal?

Comment: I think you have added  **WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();**  2 times; It's not needed in the 3rd line I guess

Comment: @AlakbarHeydarov I hadn't done that actually but after adding it in the pub file, and repeating the whole process again, it's still not working.

Comment: Did you try to reinstall the app?

Comment: @jraufeisen Yes, I have. But still the same issue

Comment: Could you please share your pubspec file?

Comment: @CavinMacwan I have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Version:

```
flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16
```

it will work